# List of items dont load from firebase realtime database on tweaking rules

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui, firebase-security

I am trying to load a list of items from firebase database using recyclerView and firebaseRecyclerAdapter. Everything works well untill i update my database rules such that the list of items created by user can only be read and updated by him.But i get this error:

> Listener was cancelled DatabaseError: Permission denied

Here are my database rules:

```
"Users":{
     "$uid":{
      ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write":"auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
```

the structure of my items is as follow

```
/Users/<user_id>/Items/item1
/Users/<user_id>/Items/item2
```

and so on.Database rules before

```
"Users":{
         "$uid":{
          ".read": true,
            ".write": true
          }
        }
```

although the write part works pretty well.

Comment: Can you share with us the error you received?

Comment: updated the question with error i am getting in logcat

Comment: are your sure that you authenticated ?

Comment: As @nisanarz commented, it is *very* likely that you're not authenticated yet by the time you attach the adapter/listener. If that doesn't help you solve the problem, please edit your question to also include the minimal **code** that is needed to reproduce the problem.